# Read into an array between lines

Tags: python, arrays, readline, file-handling

Is there a way to read a section of a file into an array using certain patterns as "barriers"

```
# --------------------
[intermediate] --> STARTING POINT!
# intermediate dir (output dir of route chopper), is route files and
#   common files for each truck ready for customer format processing

PX12RUJ = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUJ/
PX12RUR = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUR/
PX12RUV = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUV/
#PX12RUU = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUU/
PX12WLJ = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12WLJ/
#PX12WLL = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12WLL/
PX12WLK = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12WLK/
PX12RUW = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUW/
WN14YGV = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/WN14YGV/
WN14YGY = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/WN14YGY/



# -------------------- 
[depotNum]-->END POINT
```

**EDIT:** after a bit of searching and messing around I have managed the lines between [intermediate] and [depotNum]

But when printing it comes of as the following:

```
# intermediate dir (output dir of route chopper), is route files and

#   common files for each truck ready for customer format processing



PX12RUJ = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUJ/

PX12RUR = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUR/

PX12RUV = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUV/

#PX12RUU = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUU/

PX12WLJ = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12WLJ/

#PX12WLL = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12WLL/

PX12WLK = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12WLK/

PX12RUW = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/PX12RUW/

WN14YGV = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/WN14YGV/

WN14YGY = /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/tempFiles/WN14YGY/







# --------------------
```

Here is my code, I'm trying to strip any lines that start with a # or blank/whitespace but for some reason it's not cutting the extra lines

```
#!/usr/bin/python

FILE=open("/shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/lloydF/conDalt.ini" , 'r')
for LINE in FILE:
    LINE = filter(None,LINE)
    LINE = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), LINE)
    if LINE.strip() == '[intermediate]':
        break
for LINE in FILE:
    if LINE.strip() == '[depotNum]':
        break
    print LINE
```

Comment: So what did you try out yourself?

Comment: The answer depends partly on whether or not the lines in your file are sorted and unique (what you posted is not sorted).

Comment: @RvdK added code and output data, apologies for the delay

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
f=open("file.txt",'r')
print re.findall(r""+start_pattern+"[\s\S]+?"+end_pattern",f.read())
```

You can try something of this sort

Comment: I've tried your solution but the only thing returned is [] this is my regex

`'print re.findall("\[intermediate\].+?(?=\[depotNum\])" , FILE.read())'`

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i would use:

```
import re
lines_list = []
with open(path,'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines()
        if bool(re.match(you_regex, line)):
            lines_list.append(line)
```